# Saving a Google Chart Wrapper to image

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

How can I save a Chart Wrapper to an image (png, jpg, bmp ... i don't care) at a click of a button.

A normal google chart is not a problem, you just need to right click on it and save as image.

But how would you save an image of a chart in a Google Chart Wrapper???

Comment: If an answer solves your problem, please mark it as such.  If an answer does not solve your problem, please post further details so that further progress can be made.  If you've solved your own problem, please post the answer for others to benefit from.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save Chart in a chartwrwpper to an image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30851620/how-to-save-chart-in-a-chartwrwpper-to-an-image)

Answer (score 2):

I think the relevant documentation you're looking for is on the [Charts API Website](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing).  This method will display the chart as a PNG formatted image instead of SVG. You will lose your interactive features like tooltips and selections.

If you still want those features you could write a link that pops the static chart image into a new window to be saved.

Since you're using a `ChartWrapper` you will need to use something like:

```
var imageUri = chartWrapper.getChart().getImageURI();
```

The Uri it returns is a base64-encoded PNG image, which most modern browsers will render as an image if used as the `src` attribute for an `img` tag, or just entered directly into the address bar.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Sometimes my typing is terrible. I lean on editor auto-complete a little too much.